# Is there a planned release date for Entity Framework 2.0?

Tags: entity-framework

I am currently looking at different ORM solutions for a project that is planned for this spring. Entity Framework is one of the products I am looking closer at, but EF 2.0 would be quite a lot more interesting.

Has there been any indications to when version 2.0 of Entity Framework is planned to be released? With .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it hasn't been officially announced. The best hint I saw is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx), so it's probably coming with .NET 4.0. I bet they will release a CTP before that.

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework v2 will be part of .NET 4.0. You can see information about v2 over at http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign and there is also a [video from PDC](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL20/)

The first CTP of VS2010 and .NET 4.0 is already available - but I don't think it includes new EF features yet (will check on that) [download CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en)