# Where to download the latest version of Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4, release

I am using EF 4.0, at the time I am writing these lines I heard that EF 4.1 update 1 has been released and EF 4.2 is in beta. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework)

> A refresh of version 4.1 named Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1, was
>   released on July 25, 2011. It includes bug fixes and new supported
>   types.

But I only found a link of [Version 4.1.10311.0 from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18504) which date published is 3/21/2011. So I wonder if version 4.1.10311.0 is the latest release so far. If it's not, where can I download the latest release ?

ps : For some reasons I can't use live update, I need to download package to install manually.

Comment: This Page may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261235/is-there-a-planned-release-date-for-entity-framework-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EFv4.0 you mostly don't need EFv4.1 or EFv4.2. Those versions bring new type of mapping (code first / fluent) and new DbContext API which can be used instead of ObjectContext API. So unless you want to start a new project with those "new" features or completely migrate your existing project you don't need it. Real new functionality for you will be included in .NET 4.5. DbContext API and code first is shipped only as NuGet package since EFv4.2.

Comment: Do EF 4.1 and EF 4.2 generate entity's validate rules ? There is lack of this feature in EF 4.0 right ?

Comment: No. No version of EF generates data annotations and even EF 4.5 will not do that as well which is IMHO correct.

Answer (score 2):

[From Arthur Vickers:](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/11/why-entity-framework-is-releasing-on-nuget-only/)

> What if I can’t use NuGet? What if you can’t connect to the Internet
>   from your development machine. Or what if you are not allowed to
>   install NuGet on your machine. Don’t worry; all is not lost.
>
> First you need to get the NuGet package. For this you do need to be
>   able to connect to the Internet from some machine—but it doesn’t have
>   to be your development machine. You’re reading this so presumably
>   you’re not completely off-the-grid. :-)
>
> You can get the package by using NuGet in Visual Studio on a machine
>   connected to the Internet in the normal way—just install the package
>   you want into a dummy project. After installing the package you can
>   find the .nupkg file either in the dummy project folder or by browsing
>   the Package Cache from the Package Manager Settings menu option.
>
> You can also get the package without Visual Studio by using NuGet.exe.
>
> If you are able to install NuGet on your development machine then do
>   so and setup a local feed. This may sound daunting but it’s really
>   easy. Copy the .nupkg file to your local feed and then use NuGet to
>   install it in the normal way—with no connection to the Internet
>   required.
>
> If you can’t install NuGet on your development machine then take the
>   .nupkg file and rename it to .zip—yep, it’s a zip file. You can now
>   extract EntityFramework.dll from the zip file and use it as you would
>   any other assembly. Note that you will not get any of the automatic
>   project-level integration I mentioned above, so you may have to do
>   more manual configuration of your project.

Answer (score 0):

use the package-manager in VS2010 to install

Tools + Library Package Manager + Nuget package manager

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reasons I can't use live update, I need to download package to install manually.

Comment: try installing nuget from nuget.org and then try again

Comment: VS 10 installed on the machine which doesn't connect to internet. Is it possible to install in that way ?

Answer (score 0):

EF 4.2 has just been released: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx

This is a minor update over 4.1.

The runtime components are available via NuGet. The designer etc. updates for VS are a separate install.